# Python APScheduler RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi4, apscheduler

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with a temperature sensor (DHT22) and I made a script to display the data on a website (node.js). Recently, the script worked, but after I reinstalled RPIos lite, there always comes this error:

```
Error submitting job "saveTempDate (trigger: cron[minute='*/55'], next run at: 2021-11-18 15:55:00 GMT)" to executor "default"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 979, in _process_jobs
    executor.submit_job(job, run_times)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 71, in submit_job
    self._do_submit_job(job, run_times)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/apscheduler/executors/pool.py", line 28, in _do_submit_job
    f = self._pool.submit(run_job, job, job._jobstore_alias, run_times, self._logger.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 163, in submit
    raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after '
RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown
Error submitting job "saveTempDate (trigger: cron[minute='*/5'], next run at: 2021-11-18 15:55:00 GMT)" to executor "default"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 979, in _process_jobs
    executor.submit_job(job, run_times)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 71, in submit_job
    self._do_submit_job(job, run_times)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/apscheduler/executors/pool.py", line 28, in _do_submit_job
    f = self._pool.submit(run_job, job, job._jobstore_alias, run_times, self._logger.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 163, in submit
    raise RuntimeError('cannot schedule new futures after '
RuntimeError: cannot schedule new futures after interpreter shutdown
```

Here is the data saving script(temperaturelog.py):

```
from __future__ import division
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler # type: ignore
import datetime
import json
import os.path
import time
import math
import dht
import weather

print("Temperature logging started.")
dht.startDataLoading()

def get_cpu_temperature():
    f = open("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp", "r")
    t = f.readline()
    cpuTemp = int(t)
    return (cpuTemp / 1000)

def saveTempDate():
    print("saving...")
    curMs = time.time()
    msPassedToday = curMs % (24*60*60*1000)
    dt = datetime.datetime.now()

    if not(os.path.isfile("/./home/pi/RPIweb/www/data/tempandhumidity/" + (f"{dt.year:04d}" + f"{dt.month:02d}" + f"{dt.day:02d}") + ".json")):
        with open("/./home/pi/RPIweb/www/data/tempandhumidity/" + (f"{dt.year:04d}" + f"{dt.month:02d}" + f"{dt.day:02d}") + ".json", "w") as file:
            preData = {}
            for i in range(math.floor(msPassedToday / 300000)):
                preData[f"{math.floor(i/12):02d}:{(i%12)*5:02d}"] = [0, 0, 0, 0]

            print(preData)
            file.write("{\"history\": " + json.dumps(preData) + ", \"current\": [0,0,0,0]}")

    with open("/./home/pi/RPIweb/www/data/tempandhumidity/" + (f"{dt.year:04d}" + f"{dt.month:02d}" + f"{dt.day:02d}") + ".json", "r") as file:
        data = json.loads(file.read())
        data["history"][f"{dt.hour:02d}" + ":" + f"{dt.minute:02d}"] = [dht.getData()[0], weather.getCurrentWeather()["main"]["temp"], get_cpu_temperature(), dht.getData()[1]]
        data["current"] = [dht.getData()[0], weather.getCurrentWeather()["main"]["temp"], get_cpu_temperature(), dht.getData()[1]]

    with open("/./home/pi/RPIweb/www/data/tempandhumidity/" + (f"{dt.year:04d}" + f"{dt.month:02d}" + f"{dt.day:02d}") + ".json", "w") as file:
        file.write(json.dumps(data))
        
# Setup scheduler for saving temperature
sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", hour="*")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/05")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/10")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/15")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/20")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/25")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/30")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/35")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/40")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/45")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/50")
sched.add_job(saveTempDate, trigger="cron", minute="*/55")
sched.start()
```

And here is dht.py:

```
import time
import board # type: ignore
import adafruit_dht # type: ignore
import threading
 
# Initial the dht device, with data pin connected to:
# dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D4)
 
# you can pass DHT22 use_pulseio=False if you wouldn't like to use pulseio.
# This may be necessary on a Linux single board computer like the Raspberry Pi,
# but it will not work in CircuitPython.
dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D4, use_pulseio=False)
global temp, hum
def getData():
    global temp, hum
    return [temp, hum]

def dataLoadingLoop():
    global temp, hum
    while True:
        try:
            # Print the values to the serial port
            temp = dhtDevice.temperature
            hum = dhtDevice.humidity  
            
        except RuntimeError as error:
            # Errors happen fairly often, DHT's are hard to read, just keep going
            print(error.args[0])
            time.sleep(2.0)
            continue
        except Exception as error:
            dhtDevice.exit()
            raise error
 
        time.sleep(10.0)

def startDataLoading():
    global temp, hum
    temp = 0
    hum = 0
    dataThread = threading.Thread(target=dataLoadingLoop)
    dataThread.start()
```

This is my first question here, I hope that I wrote it right.
Thanks!

Comment: The error trace you posted begins with "Checksum did not validate. Try again.", but is there anything else before that ?

Comment: The "checksum did not validate" error is by the dht sensor. It's hard to read, so this happens quite often.

Comment: Is the above exception the first exception displayed?

Comment: Yes, I think so...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**
I found out, that APscheduler isn't working on Python 3.10, so I changed my python version to 3.7 and it works now.